# How do I adjust an ImageButton's width and height?

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton

I have been looking for an answer to this for a while now, but I can't find one that fits me.
I want to put three pictures in the same line in a Linear Layout. I want them to be ImageButtons, here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton05"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I get is that as the picture 'background' is too big, the weight of the button is displayed right while the height is a lot bigger than expected.
It looks like this:

[looks http://imageshack.us/a/img18/1516/x3qi.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img18/1516/x3qi.png)

And it should look like this:

[should look http://imageshack.us/a/img855/834/403t.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img855/834/403t.png)

How can I solve that without specifying the size in dp?

Comment: No need to add tags (i,e. android) to your titles. That's what tags are for.

Comment: @BobbyDigital ok sorry, I won't do it next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add  `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to each of your ImageButtons. Thats all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

to `ImageButton`.

And set a `maxHeight` for the `imageButton`

```
  android:maxHeight = "yourValue"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Activity` you could try to set the maximum height to the `ImageButton`'s width as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myImageButton);
    ib.setMaxHeight(ib.getWidth());

    //the rest of your onCreate method...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a parent linear layout of vertical orientation with garvity="top" and provide weight to child linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just include dimens to your xml and set it on layout_width or layout_height properties.

```
(dimens.xml)
<resources>
    <dimen name="button_height">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_width">25dp</dimen>
</resources>

(your layout.xml)
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/stylebuttontl"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height" />
```